# Websockets using angular and Nodejs: How to send data to specific client

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket

I am trying to use `websocket.io` with `nodejs` and `angular`. I am trying to build a one-to-one chat application. Here is snippets of my code:

**server.js**

```
 app.io.on('connection', function(socket){

        console.info(`Client connected [id=${socket.id}]`);
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.info(`Client gone [id=${socket.id}]`);
        });
      });
```

**sendmessage.js**

```
router.post("/auth/sendMessage", function(req, res) {
    //rest api to handle send message

    //mongodb insert
    app.io.emit('new-message', { message: message});
}
```

**Angular Client**

```
this.socket.on("new-message", function(data) {
            if (
                data.message.conversationId === self.conversationId &&
                data.message.sender === "customer"
            ) {
                self.messages.push(data.message);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self.messagesDiv.nativeElement.scrollTop =
                        self.messagesDiv.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
                }, 100);
            }
        });
```

Now, the problem that I am facing is `new-message` will send message to all the listeners. Although, I am handling the logic on the client side, to only show the message if it is sent by specific `conversationId`, this should be handled at the server end only due to security issues.

So, I want to be able to send to specific `users` only. I think this can somehow be done using `socket.id` which would be unique for each connection. But how can I pass this `socket.id` from client to server, so that server knows on which client it needs to send the data?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here, `app.io` and `socket`. In the first snippet, you use  `app.io.on('connection', function(socket){`. This `socket` is the new connection. You can store this socket object somewhere in the database or in memory.

Now, `app.io.emit` will send the message to all the clients, while this `socket` that you stored somewhere will send the message to that particular client/user on `socket.emit`.

In short, you need to do

```
router.post("/auth/sendMessage", function(req, res) {
  //rest api to handle send message

  //mongodb insert
  socket.emit('new-message', { message: message});
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/aaayushsingh/arimaa-nodejstest) is a small tic-tac-toe game I made using sockets. It will give you more insight on how to use sockets. This is not perfect but you will still understand how to use sockets.

tl;dr save `socket` from `app.io.on('connection'...` and use `socket.emit` to send messages to that particular client.